# Weighting recent data in a python machine-learning-model more than older data

Tags: python, machine-learning

Having a machine learning model in python where historical data is used to train the model. With this regression-model a prediction of a continous variable should be given.

Is it possible to consider the younger data more than the older? Because in a dynamic system patterns in the older data can be outdated in present and therefore should not have the same value as the younger data for the prediction.

Answer (score 1):

With the parameter [`sample_weight`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.fit) it is possible to weigh parts of the data set before fitting. For my case, i weighted the recent half of my dataset with factor 3 to the other half. Consider the dataset is sorted by date.

```
sample_weight = np.ones(len(X_train)) 
sample_weight[int(len(sample_weight)*0.5):] = 3
```

Then the parameter is given to the `fit` function.

```
decision_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can use weights in your regression model to account for unreliable measurements in older data. But depending on the statistical procedures and packages you use, this might be hard to implement.

Alternatively, you can give recent data higher probabilities in the composition of your training corpus by using a stratified sample. If you compose your training corpus from 50% very recent, 30% recent and only 20% older cases, you automatically give recent cases higher weight. This might be a more feasible and direct way to align your model with recent cases.

At any rate, I would suggest comparing the training data for recent and older cases to detrmine where the recent data leads to changes. That is, what features are relevant in recent cases that were not there before and what features have lost their relevance. This might tell you something more substantial about your machine learning model and allow you to customize it better.

That being said, this question is rather better suited for CrossValidated or DataScience than StackOverflow as it does not concern code.